# Creating an inner text border effect with outer glow

Tags: css

How would I recreate the following text design? Font is Gill Sans MT and the text color is purple (albeit hard to tell)

[image: example]

I can't seem to get the vibrant thick border and thin inner effect with my current attempt:

```css
p {
  color: purple;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-shadow:
    white 0px 0px 50px,
    white 1px 0px 1px,
    white 0px -1px 1px,
    white 0px 1px 1px,
    white -1px 0px 1px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Community
</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get cleaner results with `text-stroke`. [Browser support is pretty good](https://caniuse.com/#feat=text-stroke).

Use `bold` or `heavy` font weight for best results.

```css
body{ background: #000; }

p {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 46px;
  color: purple;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 80px red, 0 0 50px red;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Community.
</p>
```

Comment: Very cool thank you. Assuming the font-weight: black; is a typo though!

Comment: @darkace that is a real weight used in design. I was experimenting a bit. Changed it to 800 for you.

Comment: Ah hadn't heard of that term for weights. Got it!

Answer (score 0):

For a vibrant thick border, you could try the following needlessly-long `text-shadow`:

```css
p {
  /* Purely for display in the Stack Snippet */
  background: black;
  font-size: 50px;
  padding: 20px;

  color: purple;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff, -1px 1px 0 #fff, 1px -1px 0 #fff, -1px -1px 0 #fff, 0px 1px 0 #fff, 0px -1px 0 #fff, -1px 0px 0 #fff, 1px 0px 0 #fff, 2px 2px 0 #fff, -2px 2px 0 #fff, 2px -2px 0 #fff, -2px -2px 0 #fff, 0px 2px 0 #fff, 0px -2px 0 #fff, -2px 0px 0 #fff, 2px 0px 0 #fff, 1px 2px 0 #fff, -1px 2px 0 #fff, 1px -2px 0 #fff, -1px -2px 0 #fff, 2px 1px 0 #fff, -2px 1px 0 #fff, 2px -1px 0 #fff, -2px -1px 0 #fff;
}
```

```html
<p>Community</p>
```

Hope this helps! :)